# testing the order of a collection

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, hamcrest

Given a list of objects I'd like to test that they return in the correct order, but I would like to not assert the entire object.

For example I'd like to verify that they're in order by

```
id 1, 
id 2,
id 3,
```

or in another case

```
date mostRecent
date older
date oldest
```

or in yet another case

```
enum ValueA
enum ValueB
enum ValueC
```

basically I want to test that the sort I specified went through correctly but only a single property on the object actually affects this, so I'd like to specify my test with some variant of `hasFirstItem( withPropertyEqualTo ... has secondItem( withPropertyEqualTo`

I know I can write

```
 assertEquals( property, list.get(0).id )
 assertEquals( property, list.get(1).id )
```

but I'd rather do something that makes the failure a bit more obvious as to being a sort issue, and perhaps declaratively, testing the whole collection at once. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you use Java 8?  If so, I might map the property function over the list and assert on the result.

Comment: JUnit/Hamcrests [`assertThat(actual, contains(item1, item2, ...));`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains%28E...%29) should exaclty do this. You can even write own Matchers that do the check as you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use hamcrest's matcher `hasProperty` like this:

```
public class Foo {

    private String a;

    public Foo(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Object getStr() {
        return a;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> l = Arrays.asList(new Foo("a"), new Foo("b"));
        Assert.assertThat(l, contains(hasProperty("str", equalTo("a")),
                                      hasProperty("str", equalTo("b"))));
    }

}
```

where "str" is the name of the property you want to check. Note that this only works for methods named `getXxx` as it is aimed to test JavaBeans.

Comment: isn't `contains`  unordered?meaning that if  `new Foo("b")` is the first object  it'll still pass?

Comment: No, [containsInAnyOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder%28java.util.Collection%29) checks unorded wise. contains will check item1 against item1 and so on

Comment: naming... thanks, I assumed incorrectly that contains, was similar in function to a Collection.contains.

Comment: @xenoterracide agreed, it would make more sense and be less confusing to have `containsInOrder` and `contains` (in any order) IMO

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about this would be to simply sort your list according to the given property and then compare the sorted list to the original:

```
public class MyObjectIdComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {

    @Override
    public int compare (MyObject a, MyObject b) {
        return a.getId().compareTo(b.getId());
    }
}

ArrayList<MyObject> orig = getListFromSomewhere();
ArrayList<MyObject> sorted = new ArrayList<>(orig);
Collections.sort (sorted, new MyObjectIdComparator());

assertEquals ("orig list is in the wrong order, sorted, orig);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `assertNotEquals` instead of `assertEquals` for the test to pass?

Comment: @ChetanKinger The way I understand the OP, he has "production" code that generates a list in a way that's ordered by some property. If explicitly sorting the list by that property does **not** change it we can deduce it was already sorted, as expected - hence, the use of `assertEquals`.

Comment: `assertEquals` would make sense in that case. That being said, I am unable to find enough content in the OP that supports your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you iterate over the collection and report the first case where the property of interest failed?

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size()-1; ++i) {
 if (list.get(i) > list.get(i+1)) {
    fail(String.format("%s > %s; in the wrong place in the sorted list for index %d",
        list.get(i), list.get(i+1), i));
 }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `list.get(i) > list.get(i+1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a message in your assert command,

```
assertEquals("Sort out of order at index " + i, expected.get(i), list.get(i));
```

or,

```
assertSame("Sort out of order at index " + i, expected.get(i), list.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that property object implements **Comparable** interface:

```
Object previous = list.get(0);

for (Object element : list) {
    assertTrue(previous.getProperty().compareTo(element.getProperty()) <= 0);
    previous = element;
}
```